# Modify Devise SAML Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, saml

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise with Devise SAML Authenticatable for my Account system.

I've got the SAML working and all, but am trying to work out one thing.

I'd like to change one of the SAML attributes before saving it (since it is formatted incorrectly). Essentially, the Account's SAML request is given a `role` attribute which is one of the following `Group_admin`, `Group_consumer`, `Group_supplier`. I have a `role` field in my `Account` model enumerated as follows:

```
enum role: [:admin, :consumer, :supplier]
```

Clearly I can't directly set `role` because `Group_admin != admin` (etc.). Is there a way to modify the SAML attribute that is given before `Devise` saves the field?

I've tried a `before_save` filter to no avail.

```
before_save :fix_role!

private
def fix_role!
  self.role = self.role.split('_')[1]
end
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I can post any other code if necessary, I'm just not sure what else is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do the following to fix the problem:

`attribute-map.yml`

```
"role": "full_role"
```

`account.rb`

```
before_save :set_role!
attr_accessor :full_role

private
  def set_role!
    self.role = self.full_role.split('_')[1]
  end
```

Essentially, I used an `attr_accessor` to store the incorrectly formatted role given from the SAML response and a `before_save` filter to correctly set the "real" role field.